# Is there a way to import an argument list to find before running -exec?

Tags: bash, find, xargs

I'm writing a script that performs a grep on .php files, but I also want it to perform the same grep on any files that are included by the .php files.

I'm using the PHP function

```
get_included_files();
```

to generate a list of included files (this list is then saved to a file) and I want my find to execute a grep on both the .php files found by the find, and all the files listed in my file list.

I've tried the following:

```
find -iname \*.php -exec grep 'foo' $(cat list.txt) {} +

find -iname \*.php | xargs -I {} grep 'foo' $(cat list.txt) {}
```

In both cases, I get either:

/usr/bin/find: Argument list too long

/usr/bin/xargs: Argument list too long

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can't you just run `grep` twice?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to avoid your problem by first constructing the joined list, then using `xargs` to provide it to `grep` :

```
find -iname \*.php | cat list.txt - | xargs grep 'foo'
```

Note that the `-` in `cat`'s arguments refers to stdin in this context, that is the list of files returned by `find`.

You could also insert a `sort -u` in there if you want to avoid duplicates.

My supposition on your error is that the content of `list.txt` itself is enough to break the `grep call` ; both `find` and `xargs` would detect that and refuse to launch the command, without any regards for its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In your commands, all file names in *list.txt* are first passed to find/xargs as positional arguments. In your case, this file contains more names than the limitation of the [OS](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6060).

So just run grep for each name in *list.txt*:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    grep 'foo' "$line"
done < list.txt
```